# エラーEL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type がでる

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf, jpa

以下のページを参考にコードを書いておりました。

[【Spring Boot】PostgreSQLに接続してDBのデータを取得する【Spring Boot ハンズオン第2回】](https://uha-blog.com/java/spring-boot-postgresql/)

`http://localhost:8080/book-list` にブラウザからアクセスすると次のエラーが出ます。

```
EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'com.uhablog.model.Book' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

#### 試したこと

1. html内の`<td th:text="*{id}"></td>を<td th:text="*{book.id}"></td>`のように変更する
   →`EL1008E: Property or field 'id' cannot be found on object of type 'com.uhablog.model.Book' - maybe not public or not valid?`
2. Book.java内のフィールドをprivateからpublicへ変更する
   →期待通りのページが表示される

[Accessing Data with JPA](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)でもprivateとしており、なぜpublicではエラーが出るのかわからないためアドバイスをいただきたいです。

環境：
OS: Windows11
Editor: Eclipse
Browser: Google Chrome

**追記**
コードは以下の通りです。

Book.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "booksinfo")
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id")
        // 本のidを保持するフィールド
        private Integer id;
    
        @Column(name = "title")
        // 本のタイトルを保持するフィールド
        private String title;
    
        @Column(name = "price")
        // 本の値段を保持するフィールド
        private Integer price;
    }
```

BookRepository.java

```
public interface BookRepository extends
        JpaRepository<Book, Integer> {
}
```

BookService.java

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class BookService {

    @Autowired
    BookRepository repository;

    /**
     * データベースから本の一覧を取得する
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public List<Book> findAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

BookController.java

```
@Controller
public class BookController {

    @Autowired
    BookService service;

    @GetMapping("/book-list")
    public String bookList(Model model) {

        // serviceを使って、本の一覧をDBから取得する
        List<Book> bookList = service
                .findAll();
        // modelに本の一覧を設定して、画面に渡す
        model.addAttribute("bookList",
                bookList);
        // bookList.htmlの表示
        return "bookList";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

おそらく`Book` のフィールドに対する getter が実装されていないのでしょう。
リンク先のコードでいうと

```java
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "booksinfo")
public class Book {
// 後略
```

の、 [`@Data`](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data) を書き漏らしているのではないでしょうか。

---

問題が再現するコードを載せるべきです。
リンク先サイトの通りに実装できているのであればエラー無く実行できるはずなので、問題は質問者が実装したコードにあるはずです。それ無しに参考元(正しいコード)だけ示されても普通はわかりません。
(もう少しいうと、質問文が推敲されていないように思われます)

---

Lombok の[セットアップがEclipse](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse)に対して行われていないのだ考えられます。
[質問文中にあるリンク先の解説](https://uha-blog.com/java/eclipse-install/)では Pleiades All in One を利用しているようですが、おそらくこのパッケージには最初からLombokが入っているのでしょう。
素の Eclipse では自身でセットアップする必要があります。

検索すると日本語解説もヒットする([例](https://qiita.com/ponsuke0531/items/c2dac01e444f510310ae))ので、それらを参考にして、EclipseにLombokをセットアップしてください。

1. [`lombok.jar`](https://projectlombok.org/download) をダウンロードする
2. `java -jar lombok.jar` コマンドでインストールダイアログを起動する
3. eclipse のディレクトリを指定してセットアップ処理を実行する

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。ご指摘の通りですのでコードを追記いたしました。Bookフィールドを確認しましたが、@Dataアノテーションは抜けておりませんでした。

Comment: 回答追記しました。

Answer (score 0):

1. Lombokがインストールされているか確認する
2. @Dataを@Setter, @Getterで書き換えてみる
3. Setter, Getterを@Dataに戻す
4. Outline Viewにセッター、ゲッターが表示されればOK